# What uwsgi caching framework cache key‘s content?

Tags: python, caching, rss, uwsgi

My Python web application starts with `uwsgi --cache2 name=mycache,items=100000`, I found it uses more RSS memory than starting with `uwsgi --cache2 name=mycache,items=1`.

In the uwsgi log, I find a line like this:

`*** Cache "mycache" initialized: 2111MB (key: 2136 bytes, keys: 213600000 bytes, data: 2000000000 bytes, bitmap: 12500 bytes)`

I guess the additional RSS usage is `key * items = keys(213600000 bytes)`. But I wonder why the `key` has 2136 bytes, what's the content in `key`?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Caching.html#keysize-key-size the default key size is 2048 bytes.

Not sure where the difference of 88 bytes comes from, but you can configure it if you want.

My guess is that the developers considered that key size a good length for a typical application of the caching framework: caching responses for a given URL.